# In the function $r :\mathbb{R} − \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$, what effect does the "$-\{0\}$" have on the domain?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The full function is: $r : \mathbb{R} − \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $r(x) = 6 / x$.

Comment: Is $r$ defined for $x=0$? What is the domain then?

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. All it does is exclude 0 as it is undefined. Thank you for guiding me to the light!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

community wiki answer so the post can be closed

The reason the function $r(x) = \dfrac{6}{x}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}$ is that $r$ is undefined at $x = 0$.